# Change directory through bash script without messing up $PATH

Tags: bash, cd

Yes, I know that I can run

```
. my_cd_script.sh
```

to change my directory directly. However, once I do that, my `$PATH` is messed up. For instance, when I type `ls`, the shell will return `Command not found`.

Anyone encountered this?

Comment: That could only happen if `my_cd_script.sh` is modifying the value of `PATH`. Simple answer is, don't do that.

Comment: The script probably uses the variable name `PATH` to store a path, clobbering the shell's search path. This is why scripts should [always use lowercase variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).

Comment: Paste your `my_cd_script.sh` script.

Comment: Seems like you guys are completely correct. I named a variable "path" without a second thought, although I would've expected shell to be case sensitive. Please post an explicit answer so that I can check-mark it. Thanks!

Comment: If you're running into variable names not seeming to be case-sensitive, then I suspect you're not actually using `bash`. Maybe `csh` instead, or some other variant in the `csh` family...

Comment: I used the "#!/bin/bash" header though

Comment: The header means nothing when you source a file with `. myscript` - it's just a comment in that case. So what's the shell or script in which you did the sourcing running?

Comment: Oh, in that case, definitely not bash. Thanks, that does clear things up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I named a variable "path" without a second thought, although I would've expected shell to be case sensitive. –  user1836155

If you're running into variable names not seeming to be case-sensitive, then I suspect you're not actually using `bash`. Maybe `csh` instead, or some other variant in the `csh` family... –  twalberg

I used the "#!/bin/bash" header though –  user1836155

The header means nothing when you source a file with `. myscript` - it's just a comment in that case. –  twalberg